# How do I diagnose cause of failover in a replicated RavenDB setup?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, ravendb

I have created a data migration tool that reads data from a legacy SQL database, transforms it into something a lot more sensible and then stores it in RavenDB.

When I try to write 22500 1KB objects in a single Raven session, I get the following error:

`System.InvalidOperationException: Could not replicate POST operation to secondary node, failover behavior is: AllowReadsFromSecondaries`

The message suggests Master Raven instance encountered a fatal error and migration tool failed over to Slave Slave Raven instance and tried to write to it. What I don't know is why.

Background information:

- .NET 4.0
- RavenDB #2025-Unstable (can't use stable build because of dependency on Json.NET)
- Using RavenDB Replication bundle (replication is configured correctly)
- Write operations are wrapped in a TransactionScope (there are writes happening elsewhere in the migration tool using a separate Raven session)
- No errors in Windows Event Log

Log on Master Raven instance contains the following error:

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.Implementation.NativeMethods.JetSeek(IntPtr sesid, IntPtr tableid, UInt32 grbit)
   at Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.Implementation.JetApi.JetSeek(JET_SESID sesid, JET_TABLEID tableid, SeekGrbit grbit) in C:\Work\ravendb\SharedLibs\Sources\managedesent-61618\EsentInterop\JetApi.cs:line 3172
   at Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.Api.TrySeek(JET_SESID sesid, JET_TABLEID tableid, SeekGrbit grbit) in C:\Work\ravendb\SharedLibs\Sources\managedesent-61618\EsentInterop\MoveHelpers.cs:line 127
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.StorageActions.DocumentStorageActions.EnsureDocumentIsNotCreatedInAnotherTransaction(String key, Guid txId) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Storage.Esent\StorageActions\Util.cs:line 77
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.StorageActions.DocumentStorageActions.AddDocument(String key, Nullable`1 etag, RavenJObject data, RavenJObject metadata) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Storage.Esent\StorageActions\Documents.cs:line 296
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass37.<Put>b__30(IStorageActionsAccessor actions) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line 480
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Batch(Action`1 action) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Storage.Esent\TransactionalStorage.cs:line 328
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.Put(String key, Nullable`1 etag, RavenJObject document, RavenJObject metadata, TransactionInformation transactionInformation) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line 468
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass67.<Commit>b__64(DocumentInTransactionData doc) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line 654
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.StorageActions.DocumentStorageActions.CompleteTransaction(Guid txId, Action`1 perDocumentModified) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Storage.Esent\StorageActions\General.cs:line 272
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass67.<Commit>b__63(IStorageActionsAccessor actions) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line 658
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.ExecuteBatch(Action`1 action) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Storage.Esent\TransactionalStorage.cs:line 374
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Batch(Action`1 action) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Storage.Esent\TransactionalStorage.cs:line 334
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.Commit(Guid txId) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line 668
   at Raven.Database.Server.Responders.TransactionCommit.Respond(IHttpContext context) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Database\Server\Responders\TransactionCommit.cs:line 28
   at Raven.Database.Server.HttpServer.DispatchRequest(IHttpContext ctx) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Database\Server\HttpServer.cs:line 582
   at Raven.Database.Server.HttpServer.HandleActualRequest(IHttpContext ctx) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v1.2\Raven.Database\Server\HttpServer.cs:line 347
```

Is there an upper limit on number of writes per session when using transactions with replication?
Could this, perhaps, be a result of using an unstable build?

**EDIT:** Cross-posted on RavenDB Google Groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!starred/ravendb/FZZ_Q1y59qI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this might be a bug. Provided a repro, so hopefully someone from the dev team will look into it.

See RavenDB Google Groups thread https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!starred/ravendb/FZZ_Q1y59qI for more information.

<strike>Will update this answer as more information becomes available.</strike>

**Update:** Writing this many objects within a single DTC session is not supported: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ravendb/FZZ_Q1y59qI/fimWkX8NZm0J